# using scriptlet tag inside struts tag

Tags: text, tags, struts, scriptlet

i am trying to disable a text field:

```
<html:text property="firstName" style="width: 100px;">  
                        <%=isDisabled%>
                        </html:text>

String isDisabled = "";
if (x == null || x.equals("")) {     
     isDisabled = "disabled='true'";
```

But the text field is not getting disabled.. Any idea??

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy to do. First you determine if the textbox will be disabled or not (this must be a string with true/false value, not disabled='true' as you were trying to do):

```
String isDisabled = String.valueOf(x == null || "".equals(x));
```

And then you disable the field:

```
<html:text property="firstName" style="width: 100px;" disabled="<%=isDisabled%>" />
```

See [here](http://struts.apache.org/1.2.x/userGuide/struts-html.html#text) for more documentation.

I don't remember exactly but I think you can also use a boolean directly:

```
boolean isDisabled = (x == null || "".equals(x));
<html:text property="firstName" style="width: 100px;" disabled="<%=isDisabled%>" />
```